Why I am getting error Can't resolve 'fs' when I am using cloudinary in next js?
I imported cloudinary like that
import { v2 as cloudinary } from "cloudinary";
But I am getting this error
./node_modules/cloudinary/lib/uploader.js:1:1
Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs'

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/cloudinary/lib/cloudinary.js
./node_modules/cloudinary/cloudinary.js
./app/(client)/create/page.tsx


I tried a lot of stuff but nothing helped. Earlier I tried to use 'fs/promises' but also with the same error. Same thing when I tried to import only 'fs'.

Is your page ./app/(client)/create/page.tsx a client component?

Yes, it is. Now i added the following code
`future: {
webpack5: true, // by default, if you customize webpack config, they switch back to version 4.
// Looks like backward compatibility approach.
},
webpack(config) {
config.resolve.fallback = {
...config.resolve.fallback, // if you miss it, all the other options in fallback, specified
// by next.js will be dropped. Doesn't make much sense, but how it is
fs: false, // the solution
};
    return config;
  }`

And the problem is gone now.

The Next library assumes you have fs installed on your environment - it's there usually, but certain third party hosting don't want you accessing the filesystem for security reasons, so the fs library may be absent.
I'd suggest reaching out to your hosting provider and seeing what they have to say.
